# Apply css on dynamic controls in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

How would i apply css style s to the dynamically created table element?? tblResult is a dynamic table i am creating .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tblResult tbody tr').on('mouseover', function () {
     $(this).addClass('highlightRow');

  });

 });
```

Is It true that .addClass will not work with the dynamic controls in jquery?

Suppose If i want to add class to child element:

```
  $('body').on('mouseover', '#tblResult tbody tr td #im', function () {
    $(this).addClass('transition');
  });
```

Is that ok??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your table have been added dynamically to the DOM, all the events will not be available to this table and elements such as `<tr>` or `<td>` inside it. In this case, you need to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all children matching a selector,
>   whether those children exist now or are added in the future.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('mouseover','#tblResult tbody tr',function() {
        $(this).addClass('highlightRow');
    });
});
```

So basically, event delegation will help you to attach `mouseover` event to these newly created `<tr>` elements in this case.

Comment: But why it is not applying??

Comment: The time the event binding code executes the tr is not present and using event delegation will bind the event when tr is added

Comment: Thanx for the info on Dynamic controls!! U v helpd me out!!

Comment: suppose if i want to add a class to particular element in table? see in edit please

Comment: You can use: `$('#im').addClass('transition');`

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you apply the css for the tr directly in css instead of adding an event?

```
tr:hover{
  background-color: #BADA55;
}
```

check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JL8kK/)

Comment: Ya!! Even i can do that!! But i want to use dynamic events binding using 'on'

Comment: if you to use dynamic events, you have to do what @Felix said, you didn't share your full html and js, so i assume tblResult itself is dynamically added. In your code snippet, during `document.ready`, you are trying to hook up the event handler to an non-existent DOM object, that's why @Felix's answer gave jquery a 'context', which was `'body'`, for jquery to observe this particular element